# Trying to connect two database tables in Sequelize with a joiner table

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to get a query of all merchants associated with a user.

There are three tables:

`user_tbl`, `user_favorite_tbl`, and `merchant_tbl`

For each, I have created a Sequelize instance.

User, UserFavorite, and Merchant.

I am trying to do a query that will get me, per user, every merchant favorited via the user_favorite_tbl.

Here is my code:

```
public async fetch_user_with_favorite() {
    let favMerchants = await User.findAll({
        attributes: ["given_name", "family_name", "email"],
        include: [
            {
                model: UserFavorite,
                attributes: ["merchant_id"],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Merchant,
                        attributes: ["name"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
    return favMerchants;
}
```

And

```
User.belongsToMany(Merchant, { through: "user_favorite_tbl" });
Merchant.belongsToMany(User, { through: "user_favorite_tbl" });
```

However when I try to call the end point associated with this code, I get the following error:

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: user_favorite_tbl is not associated to user_tbl!
```

When I try to add this:

```
User.hasMany(UserFavorite, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
Merchant.hasMany(UserFavorite, { foreignKey: "merchant_id" });
```

I get this error:

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: merchant_tbl is not associated to user_favorite_tbl!
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can define associations as below - 
Many to many relationships can be achieved using two one to many relationships as below-

```
User.hasMany(UserFavorite, { foreignKey: 'user_id', targetKey: 'id'});
UserFavorite.hasMany(User,{ foreignKey: 'user_id',targetKey: 'id'});
Merchant.hasMany(UserFavorite, { foreignKey: 'merchant_id', targetKey: 'id'});
UserFavorite.hasMany(Merchant,{ foreignKey: 'merchant_id',targetKey: 'id'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `belongsToMany` association looks correct, however, when you have `belongsToMany`, your `findAll` should not have the middle table in `include`. `through` is taking care of the middle table association internally.

```
let favMerchants = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ["given_name", "family_name", "email"],
    include: [
        {
            model: Merchant,
            attributes: ["name"],
            through: { attributes: [] } // if you do not need any metadata in user_favorite_tbl.
        }
    ]
});
```

On a side note

`User.belongsToMany(Merchant, { through: "user_favorite_tbl" });`

This maybe better to use

`User.belongsToMany(Merchant, { through: UserFavorite });`